# Jmeter-Regular expression extractor

Tags: regex

My Jmeter response returns me 'Location' in the response header.I want to fetch this Location header and use it on my other requests.

```
Sample Start: 2015-07-24 14:46:38 CEST
Load time: 163
Latency: 163
Size in bytes: 372
Headers size in bytes: 350
Body size in bytes: 22
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Response code: 201
Response message: Processed

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 201 Processed
X-Backside-Transport: OK OK,FAIL FAIL
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
****Location: /retail/iows/ie/en/storage/servicedocs/paxplanner/2015-07-24/eCommerce.pdf****
X-Client-IP: 127.0.0.1,10.62.26.150
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Date: Fri, 24 Jul 2015 12:46:38 GMT
X-Archived-Client-IP: 127.0.0.1
```

Steps I followed:

1. I have used Regular expression extractor.
2. Enabled response header radio button with the whole location header.

Please help me to sort it out.

Comment: What is the actual problem you're having? Yes you want to extract location, and you say you've used regular expression extractor, did that work? What are we trying to help you sort out?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the **Location** field's value from the request's response, you might want to try the following pattern: `Location:([^\r?\n]+)`, the first matching group will contain the value of the **Location** field.

Above expression is based in the following rules:

- HTTP header fields are colon (":") separated `<key, value>` pairs.
- HTTP header fields are terminated by the **EOL** char combination (**CR** and **LF**)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this..

Location:([\s\S]*)X-Client

If it doesn't work then try to use a \ before - in X-Client (escaping -)

Comment: did this help ?